# Maven build failure

Tags: java, maven, heroku

I'm trying to build a maven application, but I get an error message:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project helloworld: Compilation failure

[ERROR] D:...\Spark-test\java-getting-started\src\main\java\Main.java:[73,35] error: lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.5

It's a heroku example java project, and in the system.properties file the java version is set: java.runtime.version=1.8

The specific lines are these:

```
get("/login", (request, response) -> {
   System.out.println("request: " + request);
   return "Hello World From Spark";
});
```

I don't understand where would be the problem, or where is set the source to java 1.5

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adding this to your pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Somehow maven tries to compile against java 1.5, which did not have lambdas yet (only since 1.8). How are you starting the build? Maven command line or an IDE?

Edit: alternative way, simply set these properties:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

[source](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html)

Comment: Maven is indeed compiling for Java 5, because that's what Maven does by default if you don't specify it.

Comment: Thanks Jesper, didn't know it took 5 as default.

Comment: Reference: [Apache Maven Compiler Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/): _"Also note that at present the default source setting is 1.5 and the default target setting is 1.5, independently of the JDK you run Maven with."_

Comment: its an old post don't know if anyone would reply.. however i am still getting compilation error while doing clean build in maven, i ma using eclipse maven plugin to build. it says i ma using java 1.6 though have given JRE 9 everywhere. please anyone can assist.

Comment: With Java 10 and later (and possibly 9; I never installed that), this is a real problem with Maven and it's not clear *at all* how to solve it. You need a plug-in to change the compiler settings? :(

Comment: ChristopherSchultz I have edited my anwser with an alternative way, simply setting properties. Haven't tried it above java 8, but I guess it should work the same.